# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes at login screen

Tags: swap, quota

Ubuntu is installed on a VirtualBox VM. It freezes before I can login. I get the following error messages during boot:

- [FAILED] Failed to activate swap/swapfile. See 'systemctl status swapfile.swap' for details
- [DEPEND] Dependency failed for swap
- [FAILED] Failed to start Enable File System Quotas. See 'systemctl status quotaon.service' for details

I tried the following:

- Booting to the recovery menu and selecting "dpkg Repair broken packages" then "Resume normal boot". After that I can login successfully and update the software, but when I restart the system, it freezes again.
- I tried all the options in the recovery menu and also tried FSCK after booting with a recovery ISO.

Comment: how did you install it at first? is deleting and reinstalling an option?

Comment: Deleting and installing is an option but I installed Ubuntu on a virtual machine for learning.

Comment: I know. that's what I'm saying. you have no reason to care about the broken one. install a new one. probably you're using the wrong method to install. I personally recommend downloading the ISO from https://ubuntu.com and using Virtualbox (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) to run it.

Comment: @tatsu That's not a comment!  Than's an answer!  Please post one and leave a comment @ Fabby and I'll come back and upvote!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you have no reason to care about the broken one.

Install a new one.

You're probably using the wrong method to install.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution for anyone wondering. It seems it was not related to swaps or quotas.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502540/why-does-drmvmw-host-log-vmwgfx-error-failed-to-send-host-log-message-sh

1. Try to change display setting and check.

   [image]
2. Essentially what it boiled down to was a lack of resources. I allocated 2 CPU's, 2 GB of memory, and 16 GB on the virtual hard drive for it to work. Also make sure you have virtualization enabled in the BIOS settings.